# SharePoint 2019 on-promise doesn't display Phone number and Picture on People Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, 2019, picture

When I use the People Web Part on my SP 2019 on-premises site, it doesn't display the picture and the phone number (even if it is synced on the SharePoint user profile).

The only things displayed are the display name, mail and department attributes:

[image]

I try to map the AD attribute TelephoneNumber and Thumbnail photo with the attribute picture and phone on SP but it doesnt work.

The AD pictures are displayed on Exchange.

Thx all,